# Why does $C-(ax + b) = C-ax-b$, but $(ax+b)-C = ax+b-C$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does $C-(ax + b) = C-ax-b$, but $(ax+b)-C = ax+b-C$? Why doesn't the distributive property apply when the minus/negative sign is behind the parentheses?

Comment: Have you gone back and thought about this with plain old integers?

Comment: The notation $x - y$ is shorthand for "negate $y$, then add to $x$". For instance, $C - (ax + b)$ means the sum of $C$ and the negation of $ax + b$. Of course, the negation of $ax + b$ is $-ax - b$.

Answer (score 2):

The distributive property applies to the operator on its operands.
The subtraction operator can be thought of as a combination of addition operator with a negation operator on the second (right-hand) operand: $$A - B = A + (-B)$$
So $$C-(ax+b)=C+ \left(-(ax+b)\right)=C+-ax+-b=C-ax-b$$
Here, the negation operator is distributed to its parenthesized operand $(ax+b)$ on its right, and it cannot have an operand on its left.

On the other hand, $$(ax+b)-C = (ax+b)+ (-C) = ax+b+ -C=ax+b-C$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $C-(ax+b)=C+(-1)(ax+b)$ is distributing $-1$ over the terms in the parentheses. However, with $(ax+b)+(-1)(C),\space$ we are only "distributing" the negative over $C$. In the second case, distributivity doesn't apply to $(ax+b)$ because we are not multiplying it by anything, we are adding the additive inverse of $C$ to it.

If instead, we had something like $(ax+b)(-1)+C$, then it would be true that this is equal to $C-ax-b$

So, it matters whether the minus sign is for an additive or multiplicative operation. To answer your question, the reason it doesn't apply in your example is that it is not representing multiplication, but is in reference to the additive inverse